# Why does Stack Overflow have body {font-size: 80%;}

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

What is the deal on Stack Overflow having such a reduced default font size. Once you've passed the age of 50 it starts to be really annoying. And I cannot really understand the reason.

Should the assumption not be that a user instructs its browser to show a reasonable and well readable size at 100%?

Comment: The `.post-text` class sets it to 107%, which returns it to a normal size. The final computed size is 14px (for me), which is a very normal font size for a website. FWIW the site looks *terribly oversized* if you just blindly change that one value to 100%.

Comment: Aaah, now I see. This might then actually a firefox bug. Chromium also tells me its 14px and it looks reasonably sized, in but "inspect element" in firefox-34, the computed font-size is just 11.3px and the font-size:107% is scratched out.

Comment: All browsers will cross it out, because it's later "overridden" by a 100%. But the way font-size works is that it gets recalculated each time a new one is set as you go down the element tree. A 100% value won't change it from its previous value. I think it goes something like 100%, 80%, 100%, 100%, 107%, 100% (there are probably a bunch more 100%'s in there).

Comment: Also of interest: The new MSO redesign (to be pushed to Stack Overflow at some point) no longer uses this 80% then 107% method of font sizing. So that will be gone shortly anyways.

Comment: Thanks, @animuson... so now, in addition to my eyes hurting, now my brain is, too! ;)